# Will I be able to buy food/coffee at 5 am on arrival at Heathrow Terminal 3?

Tags: airports, food-and-drink, lhr

I will be going on a flight that is supposed to arrive at Heathrow at 5 am. I have a car collecting me at 6 am, which should be about right, assuming the plane is on time, and immigration and baggage takes the usual amount of time.

However, I've taken this flight before, and had the plane arrive significantly early, and immigration take no time at all. On that occasion, I was departing by train so I immediately left.

But if it happens this time, I will be left with some time to kill. Is there and food or coffee places near arrivals at Heathrow Terminal 3, that will be open at 5-ish in the morning?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, there are food and coffee places once you get to the Terminal 3 Arrivals meet and greet area at around 5am.

Caffè Nero in Terminal 3 Arrivals (go straight, on the right to the top of the ramp down to the tube/trains) [opens at 5am](https://www.heathrow.com/shops-and-restaurants/restaurants-a-z/caff%C3%A8-nero); and Giraffe Stop (do a u-turn at the meet and greet area) [also opens at 5am](https://www.heathrow.com/shops-and-restaurants/restaurants-a-z/giraffe-stop). Both places offer a good number of seats. If you do not fancy a sit-down breakfast, M&S Simply Food (on your left) [opens at 5:30am](https://www.heathrow.com/shops-and-restaurants/shops-a-z/m&s-simply-food).

My anecdotal experience, which involved flying into Terminal 3 on the first couple flights of the day (and arriving at the tube platform at 5:13am), indicates that the shops mentioned above are open by the time indicated. There may be a queue of a handful of people, but you get your food in a reasonable time.

Comment: Full disclosure: I have no financial interest in any trades mentioned above.

Comment: If you don't want a sit-down breakfast, you can also buy at Caffe Nero and take away -- they're basically a Starbucks analogue.

Comment: .. except they sell (marginally :/ ) better coffee :O

Comment: Confirmed, I got a takeaway coffee at the giraffe shop at 5:30am